# Magento 2 : Minicart Header Change

Tags: magento2, cart, mini-cart

I have button in mini cart header with title - "go to checkout". This button currently links to checkout, (**which is correct**), however I need to change this link to cart page (not the checkout).

```
<button
    id="top-cart-btn-checkout"
    type="button"
    class="action primary checkout"
    data-bind="attr: {title: $t('Go to Checkout')}">
    <!-- ko i18n: 'Go to Checkout' --><!-- /ko -->
</button>
```

File location is:

> Vender/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/content.html

Its obviously built and controlled through knockoutjs - so I had a look inside of:

> Vender/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/minicart.js

Seems as though there is a function inside of there called, **initSidebar** this calls the **miniCart.sidebar** however I can't see where it is generating the url for the button to link through to the checkout.

Any help?

Comment: Current have you used any custom theme or magento default theme?

Comment: Custom build theme. I know its inside of  `Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/minicart.js` that i need to change, but im not sure what.

Comment: No, it not there.

Comment: Where is the location?

Comment: check I post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it link, instead of a button:

```
<a class="action viewcart" data-bind="attr: {title: $t('Checkout'), href: shoppingCartUrl}">
    <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Checkout' --><!-- /ko --></span>
</a>
```

You might need to adjust the styling after making this change.

Comment: Cheers man. I don't think the other answer really got where i was going with it. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

In your custom theme, First you need to overide `content.html` file like

```
vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\minicart\content.html
```

to

```
app\design\frontend\[Your Theme]\Magento_Checkout\web\template\minicart\content.html
```

replace above code which on arround line no 50.

```
<button
    id="top-cart-btn-checkout"
    type="button"
    class="action primary checkout"
    data-bind="attr: {title: $t('Go to Checkout')}">
    <!-- ko i18n: 'Go to Checkout' --><!-- /ko -->
</button>
```

with

```
<button
        id="top-cart-btn-checkout"
        type="button"
        class="action primary checkout"
        data-bind="attr: {href: shoppingCartUrl}">
        <!-- ko i18n: 'Go to Checkout' --><!-- /ko -->
</button>
```

Now it will show View Cart link there.

Comment: Yes, i know this. I don't want to change the button from a button to a different element, i want to alter the button url location, i don't want to change the button element at all, if anything i only want to alter the js.

Comment: I update answer. Please check now.

Comment: That doesn't work, you can't pass through a href onto a button & I know the button url is set inside of the js. Doing it like this just results in the button not doing anything.